# Charge all the images before displaying the website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know that this is a question asked a lot of times here but my situation is a little bit different. I want the images to load even if they are not being displayed or in the code. I have something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div class="photo></div>    
</div>

<div id="thumbnails>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.thumb:nth-of-type(1)').click(function(){
    $('.photo').css('background','url(css/img/1.jpg)');
});

$('.thumb:nth-of-type(2)').click(function(){
    $('.photo').css('background','url(css/img/2.jpg)');
});

$('.thumb:nth-of-type(3)').click(function(){
    $('.photo').css('background','url(css/img/3.jpg)');
});

$('.thumb:nth-of-type(4)').click(function(){
    $('.photo').css('background','url(css/img/4.jpg)');
});
```

I know it's not the best to do this, but it's the easiest for me. The problem is that when I click on the photo it changes but takes a time to load and it looks bad. Is there a way to load the images even if they didn't appeared on the page/code yet?

Comment: How is your situation different? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery

Comment: All that hard stuff I don't understand. I just want to know a simple way to achieve this.

Comment: If there was a simple way, the answers you've seen would be simple.

Comment: This is not a duplicate

Comment: I know, people here is too rude and unfriendly sometimes

Answer (score -1):

Put multiple

```
<div class="photo"></div>
```

With an "active" class for the active background and load the bckgnd when you load the page.

Then just change the "active" class from one photo to the other.